# Solr query based on number of returned docs

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like to have a query in Solr which return a number of docs based on a specific field.
Let's say I would like to return a 5 docs based on a Category Trail. So, if my Category Trail is **Home/Men/Watches**, I want exactly 5 docs with this Category Trail. If there are, let's say, just 3 docs available, I would like to go back on the trail and return the remaining 2 docs which have the Category Trail Home/Men/etc.

Is there any posibility to do this in Solr in a single query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to formulate your query so that the more specific matches are ranked higher than the less specific matches. Depending on your specifics, something like

```
trail:"home/men/watches"^10 trail:"home/men"
```

would work. Note the higher weight associated to the more exact match.

Comment: Hei, this is the solution I thought about and it seems it works. Thank you very much :) Do you know a good tutorial/article where I can read more about boosting scores and how boosting influences scores calculations? Thank you :)

Comment: I can do better - you can use this to see all the contributions to the final score of each document: http://explain.solr.pl/